# Bootstrap Responsive Image Attempts Behave Differently In Safari, Chrome, FF

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, safari

I am trying to style an image that should fit into a navigation bar of a site and serve as the logo. The problem I am having is that it appears differently in the three main browsers.

To be explicit, when I play with the `height` property and make the image appear well in FF, it becomes too out-of-size for Safari and vice versa. When it comes to Chrome, the behavior is even stranger. For some reason, it simply refuses to even acknowledge that the pertinent class exists. When I check in `Page Source Code` and navigate to the CSS in question, the class is not there. The class that is missing is called `.logo-img` in the code below.

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand"><img src="{% static "tshirt-theme/img/logo-kindbook.png" %}" class="logo-img" alt="Shirt Store"></a>
                    <div class="navbar-buttons">
                        <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle navbar-btn">Menu<i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

rest is omitted for brevity

**CSS:**

```
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #333333;
}

img.logo-img {
    height: 300%; !important
}

.logo-img > img {
    height: 300%; !important
}
```

Please forgive the `!important` as I was using it in attempts to troubleshoot and hack something together.

**Firefox:**

[image]

**Safari:**
[image]

**Chrome:**
Image blows up to its full resolution and occupies the entire page.

The question is why does this happen (especially Chrome not registering the CSS class) and how could I come up with something that will be cross-browser-compatible?

Comment: Where you want to show your logo In a nav bar and what is the dimension?

Comment: The original image is about 2000x1500px. I would like it to stay in the left area and occupy about 90% of the height of the `<div class=container>`

Comment: Reduce the dimension and then try.

Comment: that is not the problem. I have tried that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bootstrap 3 then you should reduce then image size and then remove the `navbar-brand` padding.

For further details [bootstrap navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

```css
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px !important;
}
.largeImg .navbar{
 min-height:151px;
}
.largeImg .navbar-nav>li>a{
padding-top:65px;
padding-bottom:65px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class=container>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/70x50"></a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <div class="largeImg">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x150"></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist move container div outside the nav and reduce the size of the logo.

Comment: Remove what where?

Comment: This still does not address the Chrome issue. Chrome is refusing to see these styles.

Comment: I am using chrome and it's perfectly fine in FF, Safari, IE 10+ and Chrome.

Comment: What is the resolution of the placeholder you are using?

Comment: Create a custom style sheet like `styel.css` and add this just after your `bootstrap.css`. Then you can easily modify the bootstrap style.

Comment: It's mentioned `70x50`

Comment: 70x50 is way too small for my case. I do not want a small image. I want a large image to take the size of the container and appear small.

Comment: I already have a custom style. That is where i am changing it.

Comment: Then you need to increase the navbar height too. Let me edit the above ans. with a large image.

Comment: Updated, hope this will help you.

Comment: I still do not think this is it. IF I understand correctly, in your example the navbar scales with the image. I am trying to achieve the opposite. I would like for the image to scale down and take size appropriate for the navbar. Am I missing something?

Comment: In your case, this is the only way. In my experience no one ever use `2000x1500px` logo image.

Comment: Are you telling me it is impossible to do what I am trying to do? Believe me, it is possible. Also, I decreased the image size to about 1000x600

Comment: No, I am not, It is possible but in your case, it is not.